# Add two Characters Objects together so as to concatenate their text but retain formats from each

Tags: excel, vba, shapes, excel-2019

I am adding the contents of cells to a shape object. The contents are all text, but each cell may have different formatting. I would like to be able to preserve this formatting when adding the content of the cells to the shape, so that a bold cell will appear as such and so on.

I have been trying to take the current `Shape.TextFrame.Characters` object and add the new `Range("TargetCell").Characters` object to it, for each target cell in my source range.

Is there a simple way to force two `.Characters` objects together, so the text concatenates and the formatting changes to reflect the source at the boundary of the new text - I see the `.Characters.Insert(string)` method, but that only inserts the text, not the formatting. Every time I add a new cell to the output list, I need to recalculate where each portion of text has what formatting, which is proving to be difficult.

I was trying along these lines, but keep coming into difficulties trying to get or set the `.Characters(n).Font.Bold` property.

```
Private Sub buildMainText(Target As Range, oSh As Shape)
On Error GoTo 0
Dim chrExistingText As Characters
Dim chrTextToAdd As Characters
Dim chrNewText As Characters
Dim o As Characters
Dim i As Integer
Dim isBold As Boolean
Dim startOfNew As Integer
i = 0
 
  With oSh.TextFrame
    Set chrExistingText = .Characters
    Set chrTextToAdd = Target.Characters
    Set chrNewText = chrTextToAdd
    chrNewText.Text = chrExistingText.Text & chrTextToAdd.Text
    startOfNew = Len(chrExistingText.Text) + 1
    
    .Characters.Text = chrNewText.Text
    
    For i = 1 To Len(chrNewText.Text)
        If i < startOfNew Then
            If chrExistingText(i, 1).Font.Bold Then
                .Characters(i, 1).Font.Bold = True
            Else
                .Characters(i, 1).Font.Bold = False
            End If
        Else
            If chrNewText(i - startOfNew + 1, 1).Font.Bold Then
                .Characters(i, 1).Font.Bold = True
            Else
                .Characters(i, 1).Font.Bold = False
            End If
        End If
    Next i
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you have to store whether each character in the cell is bold or not separately (eg in an array) and then loop through that.

Comment: I tried `dim o as object` with `for each o in .Characters`, but it said that wasn't supported. Looking at the Microsoft documentation, it is not clear what the `.Characters` array is an array of, so I gave up on trying to loop through the .characters

Comment: I am slightly confused. What are you trying to achieve? **1.** Add a single cell to existing shape (with no text)? OR **2.** Add a single cell to existing shape and preserve formatting of the range and the text in the shape? Also when you are talking about formats, are you referring to only BOLD or it can be ITALICS, UNDERLINE, STRIKETHROUGH, SUPERSCRIPT, SUBSCRIPT, COLOR, FONT, FONT SIZE etc etc?

Comment: I would like to take the text content of a cell, including formatting and add that text to the textframe of a shape. I would like to then go to another cell and append the text from that second cell to the same textframe, with that second cell's formatting intact. Ideally this process would be indefinitely repeatable but in practice is unlikely to use more than about 6 cells. I would be happy if only bold and italic were preserved, as that is largely what is used - however, the more the merrier in terms of preservation.

Comment: Ok I will show you an example for B,U,I and you apply the rest :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example which takes a single cell and appends it to a shape; preserving, shape's and range's formattings. In the example below, we will preserve `BOLD (B)`, `ITALICS (I)` and `UNDERLINE (U)`. Feel free to modify the code to store more formatting attributes.

**LOGIC:**

1. The maximum length of characters you can have in a shape's textframe is `32767`. So we will create an array (*as @SJR mentioned in the comments above*) say, `TextAr(1 To 32767, 1 To 3)`, to store the formatting options. The `3` columns are for `B`,`U` and `I`. If you want to add more attributes then change it to the relevant number.
2. Store the shape's formatting in an array.
3. Store the cells's formatting in an array.
4. Append the cell's text to the shape.
5. Loop through the array and re-apply the formatting.

**CODE:**

I have commented the code but if you have a problem understanding it then simply ask. I quickly wrote this so I must confess that I have not done extensive testing of this code. I am assuming that the cell/shape doesn't have any other formatting other than `B`, `I` and `U(msoUnderlineSingleLine)`. If it does, then you will have to amend the code accordingly.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = Sheet1
    
     AddTextToShape ws.Range("F3"), ws.Shapes("MyShape")
End Sub

'~~> Proc to add cell range to shape
Sub AddTextToShape(rng As Range, shp As Shape)
                  
    '~~> Check for single cell
    If rng.Cells.Count > 1 Then
        MsgBox "Select a single cell and try again"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim rngTextLength  As Long
    Dim shpTextLength  As Long
    
    '~~> Get the length of the text in the supplied range
    rngTextLength = Len(rng.Value)
    
    '~~> Get the length of the text in the supplied shape
    shpTextLength = Len(shp.TextFrame.Characters.Text)
    
    '~~> Check if the shape can hold the extra text
    If rngTextLength + shpTextLength > 32767 Then
        MsgBox "Cell text will not fit in Shape. Choose another cell with maximum " & _
        (32767 - shpTextLength) & " characters"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim TextAr(1 To 32767, 1 To 3) As String
    Dim i As Long
    
    '~~> Store the value and formatting from the shape in the array
    For i = 1 To shpTextLength
        With shp.TextFrame.Characters(i, 1)
            With .Font
                If .Bold = True Then TextAr(i, 1) = "T" Else TextAr(i, 1) = "F"
                If .Italic = True Then TextAr(i, 2) = "T" Else TextAr(i, 2) = "F"
                If .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingle Then TextAr(i, 3) = "T" Else TextAr(i, 3) = "F"
            End With
        End With
    Next i
    
    '~~> Store the value and formatting from the range in the array
    Dim j As Long: j = shpTextLength + 2
    
    For i = 1 To rngTextLength
        With rng.Characters(Start:=i, Length:=1)
            With .Font
                If .Bold = True Then TextAr(j, 1) = "T" Else TextAr(j, 1) = "F"
                If .Italic = True Then TextAr(j, 2) = "T" Else TextAr(j, 2) = "F"
                If .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingle Then TextAr(j, 3) = "T" Else TextAr(j, 3) = "F"
                j = j + 1
            End With
        End With
    Next i
    
    '~~> Add the cell text to shape
    shp.TextFrame.Characters.Text = shp.TextFrame.Characters.Text & " " & rng.Value2
    
    '~~> Get the new text length of the shape
    shpTextLength = Len(shp.TextFrame.Characters.Text)
    
    '~~> Apply the formatting
    With shp
        For i = 1 To shpTextLength
            With .TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(i, 1).Font
                If TextAr(i, 1) = "T" Then .Bold = msoTrue Else .Bold = msoFalse
                
                If TextAr(i, 2) = "T" Then .Italic = msoTrue Else .Italic = msoFalse
                
                If TextAr(i, 3) = "T" Then .UnderlineStyle = msoUnderlineSingleLine _
                Else .UnderlineStyle = msoNoUnderline
            End With
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

**IN ACTION**

[image]

Comment: This is a perfect solution - thank you very much! I have one questionn; why is the array set to have a length of `shpTextLength + 2`? I am really blown away by the quality of this answer; it should be taken as some kind of template for perfection!

Comment: That is the position after the existing text length with a " ". For example Shape has text `123` then `shpTextLength = 3` and if I add say `Sid` to exisiting shape `123 Sid` then it will be at the `5th` position. `shpTextLength(3) + Space(1) + S(1)id`